# Getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS / KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS when creating a view

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I'm creating a custom view that will be responsible for displaying some text.

```
BOOL DisplayBiggerString(Item *feedItem, CGFloat contentWidth) {
  StyledString *const tryBiggerString = [feedItem buildBiggerString:[feedItem myStyle]];
  CoreTextView *testTextView = [[CoreTextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, contentWidth, 0)];
  [testTextView setStyledString:tryBiggerString];
  return testTextView.numberOfLines > 1;
}
```

It seems that it's crashing on the line:

```
CoreTextView *testTextView = [[CoreTextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, contentWidth, 0)];
```

I'm not sure why it's causing a crashing for that view. The function inside just creates a new view like so:

```
if (self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 1)])
```

I personally haven't been able to repro this as I can only respond to crash reports I've gotten. I checked the contentWidth and it's just getting the collectionView's width:

```
CGRectGetWidth(self.collectionView.bounds)
```

and this is done outside of a dispatch_async call which sizes the string when coming from cache:

`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            MakeTextCacheWarmup(newObjects, self.dataSource.feedSectionControllerComponents.itemConfiguration, width, width);`

Is there some way to pass some width that would cause this to crash? I've tested all float values and they have seemed fine so far. Or is it a problem to create a view inside of the async block? I never add the view but merely use it to decide the number of lines of text

```
libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend
1CoreFoundation -[__NSSetM addObject:]
2UIKitCore UIViewDidSetNeedsDisplay
3UIKitCore -[UIView _createLayerWithFrame:]
4UIKitCore UIViewCommonInitWithFrame
5UIKitCore -[UIView initWithFrame:]
6MyApp __cmp_gen_92064(MYUserSession+MYMediaUploadManager.m:13)
7+MyApp DisplayBiggerString(MYConsumptionHelpers.m:12)
8+MyApp +[MYFeedItemTextCell buildStyledStringWithFeedItem:feedItemRow:pageCellState:configuration:contentWidth:textWidth:combinedContextOptions:userSession:](MYFeedItemTextCell.m:403)
9+MyApp __cmp_gen_8c7c(MYMainAppViewController.m:174)
10+MyApp MakeTextCacheWarmup(MakeTextCacheWarmup.m:47)
11+MyApp __81-[MYMainFeedViewController feedNetworkSource:didFinishLoadingObjects:withConfig:]_block_invoke.818
```

Comment: There isn't enough code here to really answer.   Got a backtrace?  How is DisplayBiggerString called?  Why does `[testTextView tryBiggerString]` even compile?

Comment: Yeah I have a backtrace and I've followed it to these points as I think they're the most relevant. My *feeling* is that the issue is a memory leak with creating the View inside of the call `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{` as it's not a main thread but I'm not 100% sure . MakeTextCacheWarmup eventually calls the function `DisplayBiggerString` but the callstack there is pretty long and involved so I isolated it to the where I suspect the issue to be in.

Comment: CoreTextView has a method that we call `tryBiggerString` but based on callstack the error happens on view init i.e.:   `CoreTextView *testTextView = [[CoreTextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, contentWidth, 0)];` which makes me suspect it's a memory leak issue as crashing on initializing a view seems pretty suspect imo. This is the backtrace after initializing the view: `1 CoreFoundation -[__NSSetM addObject:]
2 UIKitCore UIViewDidSetNeedsDisplay
3 UIKitCore -[UIView _createLayerWithFrame:]
4 UIKitCore UIViewCommonInitWithFrame
5 UIKitCore -[UIView initWithFrame:]`

Comment: BTW:  The `tryBiggerString` variable in `DisplayBiggerString()` is unused.

Edit your question and add the full stack trace of the crash.  Much easier to read than in a comment.   In general, you should *not* be mucking with the UIKit on anything but the main thread ever (unless explicitly documented as safe).

Comment: Hey @bbum, I've added more details including the full stack trace. My suspicion as I mentioned earlier is that it's a problem with creating the view in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{` which is not the main thread.

Comment: Yeah-- don't be touching the view hierarchy from any thread/queue but the main one.

Comment: I see, so there's not an easy way to debug this as it's probably a memory access issue where the view is being allocated on `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT` as opposed to the main thread.

Comment: Not really;  you're running into race conditions.  However, there isn't really a need to debug.   By definition, allocating views and mucking with the view hierarchy on anything but the main thread is a bug.   If it works, it is only by coincidence and will break sometimes, be it in the current release or against some release down the road.

Comment: "You're running into race conditions". How do you know that's the case? I've now changed the code so that we're not creating a view on a non-main thread.

Comment: Because you are mucking with the UIKit view hierarchy on a non-main thread and seeing inconsistent behavior.  It is a loose definition of race condition, but a classic one.  Any time you have something that only works on thread A and you muck with it from thread B and see crashes, it is almost always because A did something under the assumption that there would be no B in play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue with @bbum's help. The problem was with creating an instance of `UIView` on a non-main thread. This results in a race condition which ultimately crashes the app.